# How to get the proper absolute path of a file using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to get the absolute path of a file, but it's not working. My Code is only showing the *path* to the directory of my *running code*. This are the two way I have tried:

1)

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("More_Types.py"))
```

2)

```
import os
print(os.path.realpath("More_Types.py"))
```

But I continue to get the full path to my running program. How can I get the correct path to file, that is located some where else in my Computer?

PS: I am sorry I can't provide the output because it will reveal all the folders to my running program.

Comment: You have to have some way of accessing the file—like a valid relative path from the current working directory to the file's location—before you can turn that into an absolute path. If you have no idea where the file is except "some where else in my Computer", the only way to get an absolute path would be to search the whole computer to find it.

Comment: @abarnert That's what I need

Comment: So you have no idea where the file is? You _could_ solve that by walking the entire filesystem in Python, but that's probably a bad idea. (It will be slow, you may not have access to every directory you need to traverse to get there without having multiple roots to start from, etc.) Depending on your platform, you probably have something like Spotlight or Windows Desktop Search or Dash or Beagle, or at least locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`More_Types.py`, `subdir/More_Types.py` and `../More_Types.py` are relative paths.

**Outcome**

If you provide a relative path, `realpath` and `abspath` will return an absolute path relative to the current working directory. So essentially, they behave like `os.path.join` with the current working directory as first argument:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'More_Types.py') == os.path.abspath('More_Types.py')
True
```

This explains, why you get the result you explained.

**Explanation**

The purpose of `abspath` is to convert a relative path into an absolute path:

```
>>> os.path.abspath('More_Types.py')
'/home/meisterluk/More_Types.py'
```

Unlike `abspath`, relpath also follows symbolic links. Technically, this is dangerous and can get you caught up in infinite loops (if a link points to any of its parent directories):

```
>>> os.path.abspath('More_Types.py')
'/net/disk-user/m/meisterluk/More_Types.py'
```

**Proposed solution**

However, if you want to retrieve the absolute path relative to some other directory, you can use `os.path.join` directly:

```
>>> directory = '/home/foo'
>>> os.path.join(directory, 'More_Types.py')
'/home/foo/More_Types.py'
>>>
```

I think the best answer to your question is: You need to specify the directory the file is in. Then you can use `os.path.join` to create an absolute filepath.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you want:

```
import os
a='MoreTypes.py'

for root , dirs , files in os.walk('.') :

    for file in files:
        if file==a:
            print(os.path.join(root,file))
```